# Bluetooth no device detected

Tags: bluetooth

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Watched few videos and searched in vain any fix for the bluetooh problem. Nothing worked so far, does anyone have an ideia how to get this bluetooth working again.

I've ran `sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`

```
[    5.405475] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.405569] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    5.405571] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.405575] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.405578] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.405583] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.428523] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware timestamp 2022.5 buildtype 1 build 38020
[    5.436025] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-0041-0041.sfi
[    5.436038] Bluetooth: hci0: Boot Address: 0x100800
[    5.436041] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware Version: 132-5.22
[    5.436043] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware already loaded
[    5.765042] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.765047] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.765054] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.765869] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[    8.818380] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    8.818388] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    8.818392] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: Which device? `lspci` and `lsusb`?

Comment: anything from `bluetoothctl` you might want to try `power on` and `scan on` when using bluetoothctl

Comment: Hi - Please edit your question to include: What is the type and model of device you are trying to connect, what steps you've taken so far in trying to connect (was this through the Settings app's Bluetooth panel, for example), and if anything else changed on your device when this stopped working (since your question mentioned getting it working "again").